# pgAdmin is consuming too much ram in Server

Tags: performance, pgadmin, postgresql-performance

I am a developer yesterday I have noticed something odd with my server as pgAdmin is taking 11.2g of Ram I got Nagios alert for that is it normal Please help.

[image]

another image o/p for `top -c -b -n 1 -u postgres`

[image]

Comment: Why is someone running pgAdmin on your server instead of on a workstation?

Comment: yes, it was me who was running it but closing it has dramatically changed everything, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to close several windows in pgadmin that's it, just keep hygiene on server.[image]